# How do I send mined etheruem

Tags: mining

How do I send the etheruem I mined? Let's say I mined some etheruem. How do I send it to coinbase so I can sell it? I use Geth. (GPU)

Answer (score 1):

You can send mined ether in the same way that you send received ether. Assuming you run this on the node where you're running your `geth` instance, start a `geth` console using this command (same for Windows/Command prompt, macOS, Linux flavours):

```
geth console # I assume geth is in your path
```

Then, in the `geth` console, run this:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:COINBASE_ADDRESS, value: web3.toWei(AMOUNT, "ether")})
```

This sends `AMOUNT` ETH (or ETC) to the address provided to you by Coinbase at COINBASE_ADDRESS. You will be prompted to enter your Ethereum account password if you have one. I'm assuming you didn't start `geth` with the `--etherbase` argument; if you did, then you'll want to replace `eth.coinbase` above with your Ethereum account address in single quotes (`'`), including the leading `0x` in the address.

Comment: Well how am I supposed to know how much I have?

Comment: You can check your balance using instructions from here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts . I just realized that by "mined ether", you might mean rewarded by a pool rather than blocks you mined. Can you please edit your original question to reflect that?